# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react/

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this project, which is an employee monitoring project, and there is an interface that displays all the workspace in the project.
I called Workspaces, which is a single card Workspace, one of the workspace matrix, but I had this problem:

```
                 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

how can I solve it?
And within this file, I designed the interface in which all of the Workspace cards will appear

```
import { useState} from 'react';
import type {FC} from 'react';
import {
    Box,
    Grid,
    Pagination,
    Typography
} from '@material-ui/core';
// import ViewModuleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ViewModule';
// import ArrowDropDownIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDropDown';
import type {Workspace} from '../types/workspace';
import WorkspaceCard from '../../workspaces/pages/WorkspaceCard';


interface WorkspaceBrowseResultsProps {
    workspaces: Workspace[];
}

const WorkspaceBrowseResults: FC<WorkspaceBrowseResultsProps> = (props) => {
    const {workspaces} = props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Box
                sx={{
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexWrap: 'wrap',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    mb: 2
                }}
            >
                <Typography
                    color="textPrimary"
                    sx={{
                        position: 'relative',
                        '&:after': {
                            backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
                            bottom: '-8px',
                            content: '" "',
                            height: '3px',
                            left: 0,
                            position: 'absolute',
                            width: '48px'
                        }
                    }}
                    variant="h5"
                >
                    Showing
                    {' '}
                    {/*{workspaces.length}*/}
                    7
                    {' '}
                    workspaces
                </Typography>

            </Box>
            <Grid
                container
                spacing={3}
            >
                {workspaces.map(workspace => (
                    <Grid
                        item
                        key={workspace.id}
                        md={4}
                        // sm={mode === 'grid' ? 6 : 12}
                        xs={12}
                    >
                        <WorkspaceCard workspace={workspace}/>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
            <Box
                sx={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    mt: 6
                }}
            >
                <Pagination count={3}/>
            </Box>
        </div>
    );
};


export default WorkspaceBrowseResults;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first time when the program is running the value of workspaces is undefined so there is two way for solve it first give initial value for that second use if condition till if  workspaces were empty react ignore the command